# Analytics Database manager not compatible with Sitecore 8.2 Update 7

Tags: xdb, sitecore-marketplace

I'm running Sitecore 8.2 Update 7, and I'm trying to use the [Analytics Database Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Analytics_Database_Manager.aspx) from the Sitecore Marketplace to prune some of my old Analytics Database. The issue is that after I install the Analytics Database Manager, I get the following error:

> Exception System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.10.0.62, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
>   'MongoDB.Driver, Version=1.10.0.62, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f686731cfb9cc103'    at
>   ADM.Core.AnalyticsIndexManager.GetRecordsInPoolCount()    at
>   ADM.Controllers.ADMOperationsController.GetStatus()    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)

After doing some research, I figured out that it would appear that Sitecore updated the version of the MongoDB driver that it was using in 8.2 Update 5, and that this tool has not been updated since January of 2017. Also from our research, it looks like the new version of the MongoDB.Driver is not backwards compatible with version 1.10. This means that I do not have a clear path forward for pruning my Sitecore database.

After doing some brainstorming, my team has come up with a few different paths forward, but we are not sure of the best approach. Here's what we came up with:

1. Decompile the `Sitecore.AnalyticsDatabaseManager.dll` change the reference to the correct version of the MongoDB.Driver, and hope that we don't have a lot of problems.
2. Setup a new Sitecore 8.2 Update 4 instance and point that to our MongoDB, and hope that we don't have any issues with the Update 4 and Update 7 MongoDB calls conflicting with each other.
3. Do our own MongoDB queries, hoping that we don't blow anything up with our limited knowledge of how Sitecore is using the MongoDB data.

Is there a better option than the 3 that I've lined out here? Is there a different tool that I should be using instead of ADM?

Comment: I have taken a look at the dropbox DLL that was provided as part of the comments from FYODOR STEPANOV, but upon comparing the decompiled code of the 2 DLLs, there are enough differences that I'm not sure that I can trust it to function properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a Sitecore Support ticket, and they provided a DLL for me that is a supported fix for this issue. So, if you encounter this issue, all you have to do is let Sitecore know that you need the fix specified in my support ticket number(**521399**) and they should be able to get it for you. I hope that this is helpful for someone else!

Comment: Please include a reference number to speed up the process should someone else run into the same issue.

Comment: They didn't give me a reference number. I'm not sure how to get them to give me a reference number. Do you know how?

Comment: Does the DLL have a 6 digit number in the name? Otherwise, the ticket id from your unique URL should be sufficient.

Comment: Nope, no 6 digit number. I'll update my answer to have my Sitecore Ticket number in it. Thanks for the help!